# How far a loopback packet sent from an application layer goes on TCP/P layers?

Tags: ethernet, ping, tcpip, loopback

Assuming that I want to check if my ethernet card is working fine, if I send a ping from a cmd on Windows, how far the sent packet will go? I mean, the packet will fall down over all the TCP/IP layers and protocols until the phisical layer and then return to the same ethernet card?  Is this packet visible outside the loopback interface?

How loopback path really works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you pinging within the same computer? To my knowledge, it will not traverse the entire stack once it finds the address is local. 
You may be able to obtain some helpful information by checking the arp cache via "arp -a"

see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786759%28v=ws.10%29.aspx